# Cannot read property 'clone' of undefined

Tags: javascript, ajax, fullcalendar

I'm using Fullcalendar and I'm trying to update events. I'm trying to make an ajax callback to get def edit of that event. The route would be /controls/:id/edit, so I've built this ajax callback:

```
eventClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
                console.log(date.id)
                console.log(jsEvent)
                console.log(view)
                 $.ajax({
                  type: "GET",
                  url: "/controls/"+date.id+"/edit",
                  });

            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', event);

}
```

The code of the controls_controller.rb is this:

```
def edit
    if request.xhr?
        @control = Control.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

My problem is that when I click on one event the console tells me "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clone' of undefined". I don't know what that means. I think I'm doing it right but it doesn't work. Anyone could help me?? Thank you in advance.

Comment: jsfiddle, if you can that would help me to help you :)

Comment: Ok, this is the link http://jsfiddle.net/daviddsr/58fsceLd/1/ I had never used jsfiddle. The problem is that I'm using Rails and jsFiddle just let me put HTML, CSS and JavaScript so...I don't know if it will help you to much. Maybe if I pass you my repository in GitHUb could help you more

Comment: Ok, I've already found out how to do it. I've just used this: eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {

                    window.location.replace("/controls/"+calEvent.id+"/edit")

Answer (score 1):

Please check the event data . **Source** attribute of your event must be null or not populated. SO before calling

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', event);
```

You have to be make sure that required attribute of your fullcalendar event must be populated. Here is the link for required and optional fieldfor event object.

http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/